# mapbox access token - where do i place it?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet, mapbox

I was wondering if anyone could help me with where exactly I put my mapbox access token. I don't believe I'm doing this correctly. any help would be appreciated

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk......';

var mapboxTiles = 
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/examples.map- 
zr0njcqy/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '<a href="http://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/" 
target="_blank">Terms &amp; Feedback</a>'
});

var map = L.map('map')
    .addLayer(mapboxTiles) 
    .setView([40.72332345541449, -73.99], 14);
```

Comment: Please check the source of this example...on the first line you set the token like `mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZXhhbXBsZXMiLCJhIjoiY2lqbmpqazdlMDBsdnRva284cWd3bm11byJ9.V6Hg2oYJwMAxeoR9GEzkAA';` https://www.mapbox.com/help/demos/how-mapbox-works/how-directions-works.html

Comment: @Hackerman thank you for responding. still doesn't appear to be working ...

Comment: Did you instantiate the new mapboxgl.Map({ .. }) like in the first example shown here ? : https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/

Comment: Have you checked mapbox.com?

Comment: Looks like you are mixing Mapbox-gl and mapbox.js (built on Leaflet) API's. First determine which library you want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [quick start tutorial](https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/) for Leaflet answers this. Let me quote the code in there:

```
L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox.streets',
    accessToken: 'your.mapbox.access.token'
}).addTo(mymap);
```

Note that anything between curly braces in the URL template will be replaced with either the tile coordinates or a value from the tilelayer's own options, as noted in the [Leaflet API documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#tilelayer):

> `{s}` means one of the available subdomains (used sequentially to help with browser parallel requests per domain limitation; subdomain values are specified in options; a, b or c by default, can be omitted), `{z}` — zoom level, `{x}` and `{y}` — tile coordinates. `{r}` can be used to add "@2x" to the URL to load retina tiles. You can use custom keys in the template, which will be evaluated from TileLayer options, like this:
>
> ```
>  L.tileLayer('http://{s}.somedomain.com/{foo}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {foo: 'bar'});
> ```

Therefore, you can also do something like:

```
L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.my-mapbox-token-goes-here', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
}).addTo(mymap);
```